# What is it? [[++[[*context_key]].yaKey]] (ModX)

Tags: seo, modx, modx-snippets

I need to change value of SEO-goals (onclick) on the multi domain website. And I found this thing on the project server(MODX):  `onclick="yaCounter[[++[[*context_key]].yaKey]].reachGoal('something'); return true;"` And if I change this text it changes everÿwhere. What is the best solution to make it works?

Comment: Are you referring to google analytics? You create a new goal within GA if that's what you require, then you can move forward from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[++[[*context_key]].yaKey]]` - this is tricky solution for multidomain sites. First modx set `[[*context_key]]` and for `web` context this means you get - `[[++web.yaKey]]`, and then modx get `web.yaKey` system setting and set it to the page. So - you need to create system setting for every context with the name "`context_key`.yaKey".

Comment: ok, but wherefrom it takes current value now(some numbers of counter and they are different in this 2 domains)? I can't find something like this in system settings or context settings. Sorry for this question)

Comment: You can find these keys in system settings as well as in context settings. To see context settings, either right click on context name in the left site tree, choose _Edit Context_, then choose the 2nd tab on the page.

Or you could go to the contexts management view from Gear Icon on top bar and then Contexts.